# Best way to set up account before first time application startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I just started a Spring boot project where my first task is to make sure that when application starts for the first time admin user account is created. I was just wondering what would be the best way to implement such functionality or to use some kind of build in Spring functionality.

Right now in my project each time when user access http://localhost:8080 I am checking if list of the users is empty or not:

```
 List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        if(users.isEmpty()){
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        } else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        }
```

If user service will return empty List user will be redirected to register view.

In my opinion for sure there is better way to do it but because of lack of knowledge I don't know in which direction I should go.

Can someone suggest what would be the best solution?
Is there a build in Spring functionality which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the account exists while initialising the userService bean: create an init method in userService class, annotated with [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html). Method annotated with @PostConstruct cannot have any arguments and is guaranteed to be started after class initialization (including dependency injections) and before the class is used. If your service is a spring singleton bean (default), then the check would be performed only during application startup.

Using this approach, it would look something like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    //some code
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(userListIsEmpty())
            createAdmin();
    }
    //some more code
}
```

Of course, in this way you have to provide details for the admin account creation in some configuration file, or just hardcode it - note that in most applications default admin has some default name and password that can be changed through configuration, or after initial login.